# How to check input field in React that already has a default value set in state?

Tags: reactjs, validation

If I have a few variables in state like this:

```
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("Jane Appleseed");
    const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("1234123412341234");
```

And I pass these values as props to a component that displays them on the screen as filler info like this:

```
    return (
        <div className="card-face-container">
            <div className="card-number">
                <FormatText cardNumber={cardNumber} />
            </div>
            <div className="card-name">
                {fullName}
            </div>
            <div className="exp-date">
                {expMonth}/{expYear}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How do I then check if the input field value is empty in order to display an error message? Whenever I try and check for the input value by using `if(fullName === "")`, it is not empty because it already has this default value that I set it like this:

```
<label>
    <div>
        Placeholder Name
    </div>
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="e.g Jane Appleseed"
        onChange={(e) => { getName(e.target.value) }}
        className="wide-input name-input"
        //Only allow input of letters for full name
        onKeyPress={(e) => preventNumbers(e)}
    />
</label>
```

Comment: I don't see you setting default value anywhere

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Sorry I edited the code to try and find a different way of doing it. I will edit my question right now. I have the default values set with ````useState("default_value")````

Comment: What happens if you try to console log the initial value?

Comment: I just saw your update. Is your default value invalid? You can just check if your value is equal to that to trigger the error. If the default value is valid, you don't need to show an error

Comment: You never use `fullName` in the `input`

Comment: do you need a default value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things.

- You can either remove setting the default value for **fullName**, and use an input placeholder instead. Since you just want to display something if no fullName has been inputted. In doing so, your initial logic would work.
- Secondly, you can use two conditions, first one check if the variable fullName is empty or equal to **Jane Appleseed**.
  But the downside of doing this is that no user would be able to use the full name **Jane Appleseed**, as it would flag it as an error.